# use Datetime to do a query in SQL database

Tags: sql, datetime

I need to retrieve a tuple from the database that have a DateTime as a primary key, the problem i'm having is that it's only working with Datetime's that have the time before midday, otherside it fails to retrieve anything, here is the code:

```
string fecha = "22-11-2016 15:56:50";
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fecha, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
modelo.solicitud = BD.Solicitud.Find(myDate);
```

in resume I get a null in modelo.solicitud

if the string fecha is like "01-01-2017 09:00:00" (before midday) it success to retrieve from database, but if it's like "01-01-2017 16:00:30" will fail to retrieve a thing..

Any help of recomendation will be appreciated..

Comment: It's probably something in your SQL statement, which we'd need to see first.

Comment: in the CREATE TABLE it is defined as -->> fecha     DATETIME    NOT NULL, i did not created the base

Comment: Yeah, that's not what we need.  We need the code that actually talks to the database, and if there's a statement instead of just using EF or something, we need that two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the DBMS you are using, fields (columns) that are defined as DATETIME are stored as a binary value. What you see is a **generated** string representation of the binary value according to either the defaults defined for the DB or a specific format you define for presentation.

You can try setting the default datetime format to something like `'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mm:ss'` (`hh24` is Oracle's way to say that you want the hours part to be in the 0-23 range; you will need to check how this is done in your case).

This format also removes ambiguities related to the American/European way of writing dates (i.e. mm/dd/yyyy in the US vs. mm/dd/yyyy in Europe, such that 3/4/16 would mean March the 4th 2016 in the US but April the 3rd 2016 in Europe).

Last, the Spanish word *resume* has a different meaning than in English (you would normally say *summary*).

Hope this is clear for you now.

Comment: Except he's passing in a `DateTime` type, so we have no clue what's going on.